# MVC.NET the ViewModel from Create POST is always null

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

In my MVC.NET project I used scaffolding templates. Initially ther were binded to one DTO model. Now I decided I wanted to link it to a ViewModel, because I have two multiselects I need to use to pass values. This is how my ViewModel looks:

```
public class CreateQuestionModel
{
   public Question Question { get; set; }
   public List<int> PoliticianIds { get; set; }
   public List<int> TopicIds { get; set; }
}
```

My Create POST method that is getting a ViewModel from the View:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Regular")]
public ActionResult Create(CreateQuestionModel question)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    int id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
    manager.CreateQuestion(question.Question, id, question.PoliticianIds, question.TopicIds);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  return View(question);
}
```

And my Create.cshtml looks like this:

```
@model PoliticiOnline.Models.CreateQuestionModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Stel een vraag!";
}
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Questions.css" type="text/css" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Extra/Chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Extra/Chosen/chosen.min.css")" type="text/css">   
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Extra/select2-3.4.6/select2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Extra/select2-3.4.6/select2.css")" type="text/css">
</head>

<h2>Stel een vraag!</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Vraag</legend>
    <div class="general-question">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question.GeneralQuestion, "Algemene Vraag")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("Question.GeneralQuestion", new { @class = "general-question-edit" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question.GeneralQuestion)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="geadresseerde-politici">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PoliticianIds, "Geadresseerde Politicians:")
        @Html.ListBox("PoliticianIds", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Politicians, new { @id = "polDrop" })
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question.Explanation, "Extra Uitleg")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextArea("Question.Explanation", new { @class = "explanation-textarea-edit" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question.Explanation)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TopicIds, "Kies je thema's (maximum 2):")
        @Html.ListBox("TopicIds", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Topics, new { @id = "select2select", @style = "width: 500px"})
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Indienen!" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function format(topic) {
    if (topic.css == 'optionGroup') {
        return "<b>" + topic.text + "</b>";
    } else {
        return "<i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + topic.text + "<i>";
    }
}

$("#select2select").select2({
    placeholder: "Selecteer een thema...",
    maximumSelectionSize: 2,
    formatResult: format,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) {
        return m;
    }
});
</script>
```

The `<script>` section at the bottom doesn't really matter but I pasted it anyway, I'm using the jQuery plugin select2 for the ListBox.

This is a way of binding the textboxes and such to ViewModel properties, I found this on Stackoverflow. I also tried the classic way using `@Html.EditorFor` and `@HtmlListBoxFor` but the ViewModel's properties are always null.

What am I doing wrong/ what am I overlooking?

**EDIT:**
I put a constructor in the ViewModel, now the ViewModel (CreateQuestionModel) is not null anymore, but the values are still default values (not the ones from the form). My ViewModel now looks like:

```
public class CreateQuestionModel
{
public Question Question { get; set; }
public List<int> PoliticianIds { get; set; }
public List<int> TopicIds { get; set; }

public CreateQuestionModel()
{
  Question = new Question();
  PoliticianIds = new List<int>();
  TopicIds = new List<int>();
}
}
```

**SOLUTION**
Commenter Yoeri provided the solution, you can see it below in my answer on this question!

Comment: the constructor won't help: it runs when your model gets initialized, so it has nothing to do with modelbinding.
I'm currently looking at it in a testcase. First tip: use @Html.TextBoxFor with lambda's rather then @Html.Textbox(""). Using strings is very prone to errors!

Comment: Have you actually debugged your controller method to ascertain that the 'question' parameter is null?

Comment: I did and I just found out what I was doing wrong, I'll post the answer!

Comment: @E.V.d.B. in response to your comment that the returned view model properties are their 'default' values, I solved this error by fixing a dumb mistake.  In my view model, I forgot to declare the `{get; set;}` for each property, e.g. `TopicId`, `PoliticianId`, `Question`

Answer (score 3):

My dumb error that caused all the properties in the `ViewModel` to be ***default*** values on POSTing to the `Controller`.  I did not declare the `{get; set;}` for each property.

**ERROR**

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    public Application App;        
    public SelectList SelectSimple;
    public ApplicationViewModel() 
    {
        // Create/Init App & SelectSimple
    }
}
```

**CORRECT**

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    public Application App { get; set; }
    public SelectList SelectSimple { get; set; }
    public ApplicationViewModel() 
    {
        // Create/Init App & SelectSimple
    }

}
```

**COMMENT**

It bears repeating that the Controller needs an [HttpGet] that passes non-null ViewModel to the View; and Controller needs an [HttpPost] to receive the ViewModel on the submit by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys, I just found out what I was doing wrong. I made an extremely stupid mistake, can't believe I've been struggling for 2 days with this now.

The signature of my Create POST method was:

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateQuestionModel question)
{
    ...
}
```

It should be:

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateQuestionModel createQuestionModel)
{
    ...
}
```

I just had to change the parameter form `CreateQuestionModel question` to `CreateQuestionModel createQuestionModel`, it was as simple as that, now everything works.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Yoeri I now understand why it was giving problems in the first place:

Initially I named the parameter `CreateQuestionModel question`, this didn't work because I have a model class named `Question`. So basically the parameter name has to be either the name of the model you are using in the Create View, or any other name as long as it's not a name of another model class!

Thanks Yoeri!

Comment: Good thing you got it working but this is very odd. The name of your parameter shouldn't matter.

Comment: Could you try to change the name of the parameter again? I was able to reproduce your issue and after renaming is back again, the binding works as expected.

Comment: I found the solution in this StackOverflow thread, where the solution marked was also changing the parameter.

Comment: @Yoeri Do you mean changing it back from `createQuestionModel` to `question` and then trying it out?

Comment: I think I found the real problem. You have a model called "Question" and I think it confuses the modelbinder.
Try changing the name to eg. "model" (or anything that's not a class in your solution).

Comment: @Yoeri You're right! Changing the parameter name to 'model' (or any other name except a name of a model for that matter) works! I'll update my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "*controller-name*",FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: Just tried it, model still null :( (and then I put a constructor in the ViewModel and no it is not null but all its values are null ...)